# How to deal with old transactions when dealing with restoring purchases?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm currently developing and testing my app with a sandbox user. Even though the transactions have been completed, when I try to `Restore Purchases`, I get as much as 32 old transactions from the queue.

Essentially I would like to alert as in `Your purchase is being restored. Upon completion this dialog will close.` and dismiss it when it's finished.

```
private func showRestoreInProgressAlert() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Restoring Purchase", message: "Your purchase history is being restored. Upon completion this dialog will close.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(dismissRestoreInProgressAlert(notification:)), name: SubscriptionService.restoreSuccessfulNotification, object: nil)
    }
```

You may recognise this method below from `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`. Once the notification `.restoreSuccessfulNotification` has been sent, the alert would be dismissed as expected. But because there are 32 transactions in the queue, the popup keeps appearing and disappearing 32 times.

```
func handleRestoredState(for transaction: SKPaymentTransaction, in queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        print("Purchase restored for product id: \(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)")
        queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
        SubscriptionService.shared.uploadReceipt { (success) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: SubscriptionService.restoreSuccessfulNotification, object: nil)
            }
        }
    }


func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue,
                      updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing:
                handlePurchasingState(for: transaction, in: queue)
            case .purchased:
                handlePurchasedState(for: transaction, in: queue)
            case .restored:
                handleRestoredState(for: transaction, in: queue)
            case .failed:
                handleFailedState(for: transaction, in: queue)
            case .deferred:
                handleDeferredState(for: transaction, in: queue)
            }
        }
    }
```

I already finish the transactions both in `handlePurchasedState` and `handleRestoredState` like this:

```
queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
```

So why do I still have so many old transactions sitting in the queue, whenever I click restore purchases?

**UPDATE**

This could be indeed an issue with the sandbox.

I tried to do a count but that doesn't help, simply because not all these transactions seem to be restorable.

I did the "hard-reset":

```
for transaction: AnyObject in SKPaymentQueue.default().transactions {
            guard let currentTransaction: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction else {return}
            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
        }
```

Now it seems that slowly the transactions are reducing to zero, which means Sandbox is now losing them.

Why is `SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction()` working, but `queue.finishTransaction()` didn't? Should I refactor my code to use `SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction()` instead to be on the safe side? Or is that just a bad day with the IAP sandbox?

Comment: They are subscriptions right? What do you mean with 'old transactions`? Don't you recognize these purchases (looking at date and product identifier for example)?

Comment: Yes, correct. These are IAP subscriptions. Yes, they are old. Like a day or so older. Why are they still in the payment queue, when they should have expired?

Comment: So these subscriptions have a duration of a day and/or they were cancelled?

Comment: In the Sandbox environment, the duration of subscriptions is very short. A weekly subscription takes only 3 minutes to expire. These 32 transactions used to be weekly subs.

Comment: Okay. Then what does the information (expiry date) in the restore receipts say? (From own experience: The IAP system sometimes behaves in 'unexpected' ways. So I can relate to feeling puzzled, if that would apply to you.)

Comment: Did you check if `SKPaymentQueue.default()` and your `queue` are actually different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restoration re-delivers all purchases to your transaction observer delegate. That is the intended behaviour.

However, displaying the alert in the way that you want is quite straight-forward.

1. When the user starts the restore operation, display the alert.
2. Then, once all items are restored, you will get a call to the [`paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/1506101-paymentqueuerestorecompletedtran) delegate method. In this method you can dismiss your alert.

Comment: Yes, this is solving all issues I experienced.

Answer (score 4):

All active subscription and all non-consumable items (purchased by the current user) will be returned each time you request a restore.

Think about it, if they would not be returned anymore after you finish, how would you be able to restore?

Apparently your app can have multiple active subscriptions and/or non-consumables for a user. To avoid getting multiple alerts, you should combine all StoreKit restore callback into one (or a few) user notifications.

Does this make sense in your situation?

Comment: Thank you, yes it makes sense. I guess I could use transactions.count to see how many are stored in the queue, Deduct the counter and dismiss the alert, when the number reaches zero.

Comment: Please see update... I'm still not quite sure what's going on.